# Eclipse Plugin development issue

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am writing one eclipse plugin and project environment is configured correctly (I believe).

I am able to compile the solution without any compile time errors.Following is the code snippet which is throwing exceptions while debugging the solution.  I am sure that all the required plugins and external jars are configured properly.

I have tried almost all approaches that users suggested on internet and nothing worked. (I even changed the code also as per their suggestions).

So requesting you to let me know the reason why I am getting below error and suggest the alternate approaches.

```
public static IProject getCurrentSelectedProject() {
        try {
            IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
            IProject[] projects = workspace.getRoot().getProjects();
            for (int i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
                IProject project = projects[i];
                if ((project.isOpen())) {
                    return project;
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Below is the error I am receiving

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin
    at com.prithvi.editor.actions.UploadAction.getCurrentSelectedProject(UploadAction.java:81)
    at com.prithvi.editor.actions.UploadAction.run(UploadAction.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Your error says that Eclipse can't find the ResourcesPlugin class.  Did you specify org.eclipse.core.resources as an extension in your plug-in manifest?

Answer (score 7):

->Open Plugin.xml
->Dependencies Tab
->Click Add -> `org.eclipse.core.resources`

Answer (score 4):

When you launch your application, you have to either specify in the launch configuration which  plugins shall be loaded (together with your own plugin), or if you have a product configuration, just the plugins and features contained in that product configuration are launched.

Normally that is working quite well, as Eclipse recognizes the dependencies between the different plugins and therefore adds all the necessary plugins automatically. However, org.eclipse.core.resources is one of the little exceptions, you have to add that manually at one of those 3 loations:

- the launch configuration
- or the product configuration
- or in dependencies of your plugin (this is the preferred)

Comment: I had the same issue. When I added `org.eclipse.core.resources` to the launch configuration, it didn't work, but when I added it in the dependency list of the plugin it worked. Strange.